# having trouble adding multiple prices to a receipt

Tags: python

im having trouble with making a receipt. it supposed to be able to take in multiple prices(as little as 1 and as many as infinite(if u wanted to go that high)) and be able to subtotal of them, put tax on it and get the total. well i cant figure out how to add them the multiple numbers up. this is what i keep getting 
(i had to remove (<,>) and put these (",") to show what it giving me.

```
when you are finished enter -1
enter price of item: 5.22
enter price of item: 6.35
enter price of item: -1
your subtotal is:  "function subtotal at 0x0314C9C0"
your tax is:  "function tax at 0x0314C978"
your total is:  "function total at 0x0314CA08"
you have bought 2 items
Thank You for Shopping at Qmart
```

and this is the coding i have so far

```
print("Qmart Receipt".center(78, "-"))
print("when you are finished enter -1")

def price(subtotal, items, price):
    counter = 0
    while counter <= items:
        subtotal = (items + items)

def subtotal():
    subtotal = sum(input)
def tax():
    tax = subtotal * .065
def total():
    total = subtotal + tax


counter = 0
price = input("enter price of item: ")


while (True):
    price = float(input("enter price of item: "))
    counter += 1



    if (price == -1):
        print("your subtotal is: ", subtotal)
        print("your tax is: ", tax)
        print("your total is: ", total)
        break;




print("you have bought", counter, "items")
print("Thank You for Shopping at Qmart")
```

Comment: All kinds of problems here, with function call and return syntax, and variable scope. You should review those concepts with good reference materials to include the official Python documentation.

Answer (score 0):

First: use the `return` statement to return a result -- assigning a value to a local function like you're doing means nothing in Python.

So instead of

```
def subtotal():
    subtotal = sum(input)
def tax():
    tax = subtotal * .065
def total():
    total = subtotal + tax
```

use:

```
def subtotal():
    return sum(input)
def tax():
    return subtotal() * .065
def total():
    return subtotal() + tax()
```

Second, and I've done that in the snippet above, to **call** a function without arguments, put `()` after its name -- just **naming** a function does not call it.  That applies to the `print`s towards the end, too -- you'll need to put `()` after each function name that you're calling.

EDIT: OP asks to show yet more fixes to their bugs as they're "still a little confused" (?!).  So as I explained in a comment, change `subtotal` to:

```
def subtotal():
    return sum(prices)
```

(**not** using `input`, which is the name of a built-in function, to name the list of prices!); and change the loop to start

```
prices = []
while True:
    price = float(input("enter price of item: "))
    if price != -1: prices.append(price)
```

I've also removed the useless variable `counter` -- use `len(prices)` instead in the penultimate `print`.

Putting together all these changes to their code the OP should have a working program.  No, OP, before you ask: I'm **not** going to do the "putting together" on your behalf -- please show evidence of *some* working neurons by doing it yourself:-)

Comment: i see where your coming from but how would i get it to add all the prices up? that what i cant figure out.

Comment: @attestedstone, your `subtotal` function suggests it need all the prices in a list named `input`.  Now that's an absolutely horrible choice of name as it would clash with the built-in function `input` which you're also using -- call it more sensibly `prices` instead, initialize it to `prices=[]` out of the loop, and in the loop use `prices.append(price)` after you've obtained each price -- not elegant, but a truly minimal change to your code (much less than needed for the truly terrible OTHER bugs you had, which I fixed in the answer).

Comment: i appreciate your help Alex. i tried doing the things you said and for some reason i couldn't figure it out and always something else would happen and i just ran out of time to do it. i have to be turned in in 15 mins. thanks anyway. EDIT, when i was puting the prices.append(price) in it was only letting me put in two prices and then give me an error and like i said i just ran out of time. thanks.